# Moving background position while using background-size: cover

Tags: css

I have a slider with a background image. When the slider changes slides the position on the background image is changed as well to create a moving background effect.

something like the following:

```
.carousel { 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background 1.5s ease-in;
  background: url('./slider_bg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.carousel.bg0 {
  background-position: 0%;
}

.carousel.bg1 {
  background-position: 50%;
}

.carousel.bg2 {
  background-position: 100%;

}
```

This works but if the screen size is over the background image size (lets say 1920 width) there's a repetition. I would like to use `background-size: cover;` which solves said repetition, but if I use it the moving background effect is lost.

Any insights?

**EDIT:**

To be more clear with the code above an image of 1920x1080 and screen res of 1366 x 768 there appear to be no movement ot he image when the class changes with a new background-position. But if I change the height of my screen or reduce the width there is movement.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#background-position: _“A percentage for the horizontal offset is relative to (width of background positioning area - width of background image). A percentage for the vertical offset is relative to (height of background positioning area - height of background image), where the size of the image is the size given by background-size.”_ - by making the image cover the viewport size, you are making at least one of these calculations in the brackets result in 0, and x% of 0 is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` at the bottom of the `carousel` class. Also, you can try to use `background-size: contain;`, I think this is the effect you are looking for.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e4b9z2to/2/

Comment: contain is not what I need I want the image to span the entire width of the screen no matter what. I need something like cover.

Comment: I've just discovered that the height of the screen (I'm checking with chrome dev tols) has an effect on wither the position is changed or not. Maybe I should be specific and write background-position-x

Comment: Try that - can you provide a working fiddle to demonstrate the problem?